# Android allow deeplinking with certain patterns

Tags: android, deep-linking

I'm confused on how to implement deeplinking on Android, since they decided not to let us omit/exclude specific urls.

Let's say I have the following urls

```
https://www.example.com/detail/:id
https://www.example.com/detail/:id/manage
```

I'd like to prevent Android from opening the app on the second url, but allow it on the first. How would this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot, if you intercept the first url the second one will also be intercepted. Android does not provide a specific way of excluding urls https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Answer (score 1):

This is possible if you are the owner of the website that the url belongs to. [Verify Android App Links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations) are a special type of deep link that allow your website URLs to immediately open the corresponding content in your Android app (without requiring the user to select the app).

**Step 1**: Create the assetlinks.json file

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.example",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
    ["14:6D:E9:83:C5:73:06:50:D8:EE:B9:95:2F:34:FC:64:16:A0:83:42:E6:1D:BE:A8:8A:04:96:B2:3F:CF:44:E5"]
  }
}]
```

**Step 2**: Upload the assetlinks.json to the root of your domain under a folder named `.well-known`

`https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json`

**Step 3**: Update your `AndroidManifest.xml` to register the intent filter to a particular path. Set `android:autoVerify="true"`

```xml
<activity android:name=”MainActivity”>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
       <data
           android:scheme="https"
           android:path="/path"
           android:host="example.com" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

This will ensure that only the path that is specified in the `AndroidManifest.xml` will be resolved.